# Change date format in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following code and in this news_date is of datatype `DATE`.

```
<?php 
     $news_id=$_REQUEST['id'];   
        $result = mysql_query("select news_title, img_name, news_date, news_desc from news where news_id=".$news_id);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      ?>
```

.

```
   <div class=news-date>
        <?php echo $row['news_date'] ?>
    </div>
```

This gives me date in "`YYYY-mm-dd`" format. 
How can i change it to "`mmmm-dd-yyyy`" i.e. `October 24, 2013` or similar

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo. Well thanks for that.. I will improve my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
<?php 
     $news_id=$_REQUEST['id'];   
        $result = mysql_query("select news_title, img_name, news_date, news_desc from news where news_id=".$news_id);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $datetime= $row['news_date'];
        $datetime=date("F j, Y ") 
      ?>

<div class="clearfix" title="news date"><strong><?php echo  $datetime ?></strong>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) and [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date):

```
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime($row['news_date']));
```